# AWS CDK C# Namespace could not be found IngressProperty

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, aws-security-group

I just copied directly from the examples provided by AWS CDK Docs from here "https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/dotnet/api/Amazon.CDK.AWS.EC2.CfnSecurityGroup.html"

but when I try to synth / deploy I'm getting this error

**error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'IngressProperty' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?**

seems like the documentation itself is not reliable or working.

```
using Amazon.CDK;
using Constructs;
using Amazon.CDK.AWS.EC2;

namespace Sg
{
    public class SgStack : Stack
    {
        internal SgStack(Construct scope, string id, IStackProps props = null) : base(scope, id, props)
        {
            var cfnSecurityGroup = new CfnSecurityGroup(this, "MyCfnSecurityGroup", new CfnSecurityGroupProps {
                GroupDescription = "test",

                GroupName = "test",
                SecurityGroupIngress = new [] { new IngressProperty  {
                    IpProtocol = "tcp",
                    CidrIp = "0.0.0.0/0",
                    Description = "description",
                    FromPort = 22,
                    ToPort = 22
                } },
                VpcId = "vpc-12345"
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might be using the v2 API DLL while refering to v1 documentation.

Comment: I just tried both v1 and v2 but got the same error.

Comment: did a clean up to test v1 and was got this error instead 
The type or namespace name 'AWS' does not exist in the namespace 'Amazon.CDK'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **IngressProperty** is part of the **CfnSecurityGroup** class so to make it work you have to change your code like this:

```
var cfnSecurityGroup = new CfnSecurityGroup(this, "MyCfnSecurityGroup", new
    CfnSecurityGroupProps
{
    GroupDescription = "test",
    GroupName = "test",
    SecurityGroupIngress = new[] {

            // The change
            new CfnSecurityGroup.IngressProperty  {

            IpProtocol = "tcp",
            CidrIp = "0.0.0.0/0",
            Description = "description",
            FromPort = 22,
            ToPort = 22
        } 
    },
    VpcId = "vpc-12345"
});
```

or add `using static Amazon.CDK.AWS.EC2.CfnSecurityGroup;`

Comment: It worked! Thank you for this